# some questions about VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a few questions. 
1. how to enable `VideoView` scrollbar? I do so

```
 vv.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled();
 vv.canSeekForward();
 vv.canSeekBackward();
```

but nothing helps. I need a streak that will rewind the video

1. I have VideoWiev a certain size. And when I load the video, I need to show it completely. I need to trim or hide the top part of some size. Do you have this component, or the opportunity to do this?

here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private Button btn;
    private VideoView vv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(myLink));
                vv.canSeekForward();
                vv.canSeekBackward();
                vv.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled();
                vv.isScrollbarFadingEnabled();
                vv.start();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no one can answer me? where I slit address? (((